# Best way to set database name in external library Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an external library FooModels which is just a collection of activerecord models belonging to a test-Foo, dev-Foo, or Foo database depending on the rails environment. This is easy enough to handle when my Foo project's database.yml can cover it.

The problem I'm running into is when I include them in project Bar where the default database.yml connection is to database Bar I need to specify that the Foo tables database is test-Foo in my testing environment, dev-Foo in my development env, and Foo in my prod env.

In each of my Foo models I can do:

```
self.table_name = 'test-Foo.table_name' if Rails.env = 'test'
self.table_name = 'dev-Foo.table_name'  if Rails.env = 'development'
self.table_name = 'Foo.table_name'      if Rails.env = 'production'
```

But this seems like a poor way to handle it. I've looked a bit into letting my class from an abstract model which inherits ActiveRecord::Base e.g:

```
class BaseConnection < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  attr_accessor :database

  @database = case Rails.env
    when 'test' then 'test-Foo'
    ...
end

class SomeTable < BaseConnection
  self.table_name = "#{@database}.some_table"
  ...
end
```

This way there would be at least less code duplication. Is there a way that I'm missing that would make this a lot easier and less messy?

Comment: You can set environment variable(s) specific for each environment. See this for example:
https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv

Comment: Are you trying to open tables with the same name in two different databases?

Comment: I provided an a workable answer but in researching this issue further I found a more comprehensive treatment here: http://technology.customink.com/blog/2015/06/22/rails-multi-database-best-practices-roundup/ and so deleted mine.

Comment: I actually ended up going with the solution provided in Topic 1 on that page. It feels dirty, but I don't see a better way to do it.